# redefine(override) class in other file don't have acess to QWidgets method

Tags: python, pyqt5, overriding, qwidget

New_Student_Window.py

```
class Ui_new_student_widget(object):
    def setupUi(self, new_student_widget):
        new_student_widget.setObjectName("new_student_widget")
        new_student_widget.resize(1100, 1000)
        new_student_widget.setStyleSheet("#new_student_widget{\n"
                                         "    background-color: white;\n"
                                         "}")
        self.first_name_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(new_student_widget)
        self.first_name_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 60, 80, 15))
        self.first_name_label.setObjectName("first_name_label")
        self.first_name_line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(new_student_widget)
        self.first_name_line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 60, 113, 21))
        self.first_name_line.setObjectName("first_name_line")

        self.retranslateUi(new_student_widget)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(new_student_widget)

    def retranslateUi(self, new_student_widget_re):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        new_student_widget_re.setWindowTitle(_translate("new_student_widget", "Form"))
        self.first_name_label.setText(_translate("new_student_widget", "First name"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    new_student_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_new_student_widget()
    ui.setupUi(new_student_widget)
    new_student_widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

New_Student_Window_Modified.py

```
from New_Student_Window import Ui_new_student_widget
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget


class UiNewStudentWindow(Ui_new_student_widget):
    def setupUi(self, new_student_widget):
        super(UiNewStudentWindow, self).setupUi(new_student_widget)
```

the New_Student_Window.py file is created by the PyQt5-tools designer and then generated by PyQt5-tools PyUIC5

When I want to update something, I have to redo the process again and again, and the file will be overwritten. So I want to modify the code in another file. So I import the class in New_Student_Window_Modified.py and then override the setupUi method

However, when I try to use the new_student_widget variable in New_Student_Window_Modified.py, I can't use new_student_widget.xxx() methods belong to QWidget that in New_Student_WIndow I can use.
Seems like the new_student_widget is not belong to QWidget in New_Student_Window_Modified. I'd like to know how to solve this problem
Thank you guys for helping!

[New_Student_Window screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBxaU.png)

[New_Student_Window_Modified screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLqTg.png)

Comment: Don't do that. The file generated by pyuic should **never** be modified, but instead imported and then used as an instance for composition or as base for multiple inheritance, so that you have the "actual" script(s) that you can modify as you wish and then the pyuic file that can be updated from the changed UI whenever you need it. Read more about it in the official guidelines about [using Designer](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html).

Comment: Do you mean I should not modify or override any method in the generated file and create other methods instead?

Comment: Exactly. In a separate file (which will be your *actual* main script) create a subclass that both inherits from QWidget *and* `Ui_new_student_widget` (which you'll have to import), call `self.setupUi(self)` in the `__init_` (after calling the base implementation) and you're done; from there, you can implement anything else you need in that subclass. Read the link of my previous comment (above I'm using the multiple inheritance approach) and start with basic tests to understand how it works. In any case, don't edit the pyuic generated file, nor try to subclass just the ui class.